# How to filter HTTP Headers for Apache Camel Spring-WS Services

Tags: apache-camel, spring-ws

Apache camel provides headerFilterStrategies for components like spring-rs and cxf services. But there is no such strategy available for Spring-WS services. Could you please advise how to filter HTTP headers for Camel Spring-WS services?

Thanks

Comment: There is currently no such support out of the box. However there is a MessageFilter that can be used, but its only on the response message and not on the request message. But its a good idea to have support for the Camel HeaderFilterStrategy and I logged a ticket:https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12783

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @ClausIbsen and for logging the ticket.

Comment: BTW, we are using spring-ws and it sends soapAction header with '*' which breaks the contract with server. So we were looking for a way to either remove this header from interceptor(which is not possible at the moment as you mentioned) or set this header correctly. I think the only option now is to set soapAction header manually for each call. Please let me your suggestions.